# Python csv reading - how to add quote to only strings

Tags: python, csv

While reading the `csv` using python csv library, it adds single quote to all the values.

Here is the code which reads the csv -

```
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

CSV file content -

> 1,XYZ (A),ABC,7.05,13.10

while reading in python with csv.reader reads row in below format -

```
['1', 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', '7.05', '13.10']
```

expected output -

```
[1, 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', 7.05, 13.10]
```

I tried using [quoting format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE), but no luck.

The other option I was thinking to convert it to appropriate format by individually iterating over the items in row read by `csv.reader(file)`

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looking at the data will you always know the first column is and integer and the last two a float?

Comment: No. The logic has to be generic enough to support later integer as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        temp = []
        for r in row:
            try:
                temp.append(float(r))
            except ValueError:
                temp.append(r)

        print temp
```

Giving the following output:

```
['1', 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', '7.05', '13.10']
[1.0, 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', 7.05, 13.1]
```

With temp being the correct format

*Edit*

To get around the int being cast to a float:

```
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        temp = []
        for r in row:
            try:
                if "." in row:
                    temp.append(float(r))
                else:
                    temp.append(int(r))
            except ValueError:
                temp.append(r)

        print temp
```

Giving the new output:

```
['1', 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', '7.05', '13.10']
[1, 'XYZ (A)', 'ABC', '7.05', '13.10']
```

Comment: First column is integer, with this approach it will add the decimal points. Also, do you think there will be performance hit with try except approach?

Comment: There will be a slight performance hit, yeah. To get around the float appose to an int you could check the string value before casting it to see if it contains a period or not and cast it appropriately.